# Is there a rel=”noopener noreferrer” equivalent in Markdown?

Tags: html, markdown

If I use vanilla Markdown can I somehow get the same result as I were to use `rel=”noopener noreferrer”` in HTML?

Do I need to use  for linking in such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use vanilla Markdown to achieve the same result as using the rel="noopener noreferrer" attribute in HTML. Markdown does not support adding attributes to links, so it is not possible to specify the noopener and noreferrer values.